# Unable to merge objects with Angular.merge()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to pass a merged object to the getData() function:

```
     $scope.query = {
        order: 'date',
        limit: 15,
        page: 1
     };
     $scope.src = {txt:0};
     $scope.onReorder = function (order) {
       var toBeExtended = angular.copy($scope.src);
       var extendedObj = angular.merge({}, $scope.query,{where:toBeExtended},{order: order});
       getData(extendedObj)
     };
```

I don't understand why I get different results if I console.log() the variable assigned to the merge or the merge itself.
In other words:

```
 console.log(extendedObj); shows: 
                                 Object
                                   limit: 15
                                   order: "date"
                                   page: 1
                                   where: Object
                                          __proto__: Object
                                   __proto__: Object

  console.log(angular.merge({},$scope.query,{where:toBeExtended},{order:order})); shows:                       
                                    Object
                                     limit: 15
                                     order: "date"
                                     page: 1
                                     where: Object
                                            src: 0
                                          __proto__: Object
                                     __proto__: Object
```

And of course I'm unable to pass the complete object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current `angular.merge` method consider 3rd parameter which goes for merging process. In this case `{where:toBeExtended}` is passed for merging process & `{order: order}` is ignored.

You need to first create whole object to be merge an then pass that object to merge method.

```
var objectToBeMerge = {};
angular.extend(objectToBeMerge, {where:toBeExtended})
angular.extend(objectToBeMerge, {order: order})
var extendedObj = angular.merge({}, $scope.query, objectToBeMerge);
```

Comment: @Cris69 could you provide me plunkr? that would be best then.

Comment: I made a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KZi46YqvDzWvG9TrQIMY?p=preview), your suggestion is correct. For some reasons this is not working on my code. Thx anyway.

Comment: Do replicate the same issue by taking object which you are using in your case.. You could get that clue..otherwise i will help you out with that.. Do upvote if it does hepled. Thanks ;)